# VBA speech recognition /audio input / voice command

Tags: vba, speech-recognition

Speech recognition may be too grand a term for this problem.

I want my VBA program to wait for the user to say something like "next" or "continue" before it carries on processing.

This is the equivalent of the traditional "Press any key to continue" loop.

This should be fairly simple. All the examples I have found do complicated things like defining lexica and registering callback functions for recognition events. All very nice, but not necessary in my case.

Maybe I can/should use some other (audio) library instead of Speechlib (Microsoft Speech Object Library)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "This should be fairly simple." How did you reach that conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad idea

So what would happen if I step away and I had the TV or radio on and someone said Next

That would be pretty funny I think...or not

Comment: This is always a problem with audio input. That doesn't mean it's a bad idea. The program will be running in a quiet environment. No TVs or radios. It's not controlling anything that will blow up or injure anyone, so even if someone puts a radio on there will be no problem if the program stops waiting by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There's no drop-dead simple way to do speech recognition.  You have to define a grammar (so the SR engine knows what to listen for) and a recognition handler (so the SR engine can tell you when it's heard something).

Comment: So is there some other library I can use to monitor audio input for any signal? All I'd need would be something like an oscilloscope and if the amplitude goes above a certain threshold, stop waiting.

Comment: Well, at the very least, you need to weight the input a bit & do some separation between speech & noise.  I'm not sure that VBA would be fast enough to keep up; can you call a C++ dll?